# Jquery each disabled

Tags: jquery, each, disabled-input

with this code : 
http://jsfiddle.net/oreli/7wdq6ktn/

I like to have the following behavior:

- When input is "disabled": the label is red
- When input is not "disabled": label is green
  (or vice versa, no matter :) )

but I still have all red or green.

What is my mistake?

thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $( ".choice" ).each(function() {
    if($(".orderChoice").is(":disabled")) {
        $(".choice").addClass('disabled').remove('notdisabled');
    } else {
        $(".choice").addClass('notdisabled').remove('disabled');
    };
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting all the `.choice` and applying the class. Use context:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $( ".choice" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).find("input").is(":disabled")) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled').remove('notdisabled');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('notdisabled').remove('disabled');
        };
    });

});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wdq6ktn/2/**

Answer (score 2):

you need to check for the current input element, using `this`. Otherwise it will always checks for the first element with that class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".choice").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".orderChoice").is(":disabled")) {
            $(this).addClass('disabled').remove('notdisabled');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('notdisabled').remove('disabled');
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: Exact copy of my answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar you are just 15 seconds ahead of me. Does that mean I just copied your code?

Comment: You were downvoted when the answer was only the code and no explanation. When you added the explanation the downvotes were reversed. Mystery solved?

Comment: I'm sorry for votes. This is my first ticket on StackOverflow :( . The problem is solved and all the answers are correct as you can see from the 3 jsFiddle. Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `each` function. $(selector) in each does not refer to current iteration element. Try this:

```
 $( ".choice" ).each(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).is(":disabled")) {
        $(element).addClass('disabled').remove('notdisabled');
    } else {
        $(element).addClass('notdisabled').remove('disabled');
    };
 });
```